# View binding does not have access to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewbinding

I have an activity with `ConstraintLayout` and fragment on it:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 ...attributes....
>
  <fragment
     android:id="@+id/containerView"
     app:navGraph="@navigation/some_navigation"
     ...other attributes...
   />

  ...other views...
```

I'm using view binding in the activity code:

```
  binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

the issue here that i have no access to the `binding.containerView`.
Does in case of `fragment` I should use `findViewById` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fragment tag ( `<fragment>`) is not a `view` it act as a `container` for other views, So you cannot access it like other views...

You will get compilation error when you try to access a non-view element using `binding`

Instead you can use,

```
supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.containerView)
```