# How should I get a fragment in an activity in use of viewbinding?

Tags: android, kotlin

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/leftFragment"
        android:name="com.example.fragmenttest.LeftFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/rightFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding;
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.// there is no 'leftFragment' 

    }
}
```

[there is no 'leftFragment'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9Mvv.png)

Since Google no longer recommends the use of kotlin-android-extension, I want to abandon the usage of `findViewById`. If I only use the currently recommended [viewbinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) technology, how can I get the fragment from the activity?

Comment: `Fragment` is not a view. ViewBinding as its name implies is for `Views`. Even with `kotlin-android-extension` you would not have been able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access fragment by using ViewBinding. ViewBinding contain reference to views only but `<fragment>` is not a `view` , it is a `container`

Check my answer here :

[View binding does not have access to fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67790410/view-binding-does-not-have-access-to-fragment/67790672#67790672)